# In AngularJS, how can one controller get data being filtered from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Says we are programming a pagination:

```
<div ng-controller="panelCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query.name">{{item}}</tr>
  </table>

  <ul ng-controller="paginationCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="n in range()">
  </ul>
</div>
```

In my `range` function, I'm trying to get items amount and divide it by `itemsPerpage` in order to get page numbers. I wonder how can I get items amount after filtered.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can save the filtered list in a variable.

```
<div ng-controller="panelCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (items | filter:query.name")>{{item}}</tr>
  </table>

  <ul ng-controller="paginationCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="n in range()">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now you can do `{{filtered.length}}` to get length or use it as input to `range(filtered.length)`.

Filtered can also be a scope veriable which in this case should be available in the `paginationCtrl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate between controllers using service. Please see below for one of the solution your problem.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('dataService', function($filter) {

  var data =

    {
      items: ["Apple", "Banna", "Potato", "Pear"],
      itemsFiltered: []
    }

  return {
    data: data



  };


});

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, filterFilter, dataService) {



  $scope.data = dataService.data;

  $scope.$watch('filtered.length', function(value) {

    dataService.data.itemsFiltered = $scope.filtered;


  })

});

app.controller('paginationCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {


  $scope.data = dataService.data;


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">


    <input type="text" ng-model="query.name" />
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (data.items | filter:query.name)">
        <td>{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <hr/>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="paginationCtrl">
    <p>Pagination Controller</p>
    <pre> Filtered Array Length: {{data.itemsFiltered.length}}</pre>


  </div>
</div>
```